# d3.js: show only part of data on xAxis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using a linear scale chart with zoom/pan functionality to display a large dataset (500+ points). Here's the code I use to construct the x-scale:

```
x = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain([0, data.length-1])
 .range([0, w]);
```

This way all data is squeezed into the chart making it impossible to view the details like in the top part of the image:
[image: example]

I'd like to display the data similar to the bottom chart (and let the user scroll to see more of the data using the pan functionality).

Comment: Maybe try making the width of the SVG larger than the width provided to your x-scale. Then the x-axis should be smaller than the SVG, and you should be able to pan the x-axis accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to manipulate the domain of the X scale such that it maps the zoom boundaries to be the min/max domain values that map to the 0-width values of the range. You can then use a clip path to clip/hide that parts of the plot that are drawn outside of the X scale range.

**It might make more sense with a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/8TmM9/**

In this example, there are 10 squares that are always being drawn. You can inspect the dom to see what I'm talking about. But, there is a clip path that is only wide enough for you to see 4 of them at a time. The X scale maps the input values of 0-9 to the output coordinates. The range is set as 0 to the width required to draw all 10 of the squares, and the domain is set as [0, 9].

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data))
    .range([0, width]);
...

var svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
    .attr('width', clipWidth)
    .attr('height', clipHeight);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
        .attr("width", clipWidth)
        .attr("height", clipHeight);

...

var g = svg.append("g");
g.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data).enter().append('rect')
        .attr("class", "area").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .attr('x', xScale)
        .attr('width', rectWidth)
        .attr('height', rectHeight)
        .style('fill', d3.scale.category20());
```

Initially, this will draw the first four rectangles in the visible pane. By manipulating the domain so that it is instead [1,10] or [2,11] or even [-1, 8], we can effectively shift the drawn elements left and right so that a different span of the plot is drawn in the visible area.

```
// Pan Left
xScale.domain([xScale.domain()[0] - 1, xScale.domain()[1] - 1]);

// Pan Right
xScale.domain([xScale.domain()[0] + 1, xScale.domain()[1] + 1]);
```

This technique is identical whether you are doing it with squares or plots.

Mike Bostock has an example that does this with plots in the manner you are attempting here as well: **Focus+Context http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367**